# how to dynamically resizing an object according to tree view size

Tags: c#, vb.net

i'm attempting to create a simple order menu by combining a Treeview and NumericUpDown function as shown in the image provided in the link below

https://i.stack.imgur.com/lMB4n.jpg

the problem is, whenever i expand or collapsed the child nodes, the NumericUpDown object will not follow suits. I tried solve the problem with the following code, however it doesn't feels right as absurd amount of codes to tweak the position for every object will be needed as the child nodes increase. So is there a possible way of locking the position of an object to the respective node? I'm very new to treeview command so any advices are welcome!

```
    NumericUpDown1.Location = New Point(NumericUpDown2.Location.X - 0, NumericUpDown2.Location.Y - 32)
```

Comment: The issue here is that there is no inherent relation set up between the treeview items and the numeric textboxes. What you need is for the numeric textboxes to be **part of** the items, so that any actions (e.g. show/hiding) automatically occurs for the textbox too. But this issue runs deep: you seem to use hardcoded textboxes, but treeviews should be more open to having a dynamic amount of items in them. Are you really going to want to manually add/handle extra textboxes whenever a new item appears in the list?

Comment: This is only easy to do in WPF.  Absurd code required for Winforms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by making NumericUpDowns as we go. It took me a while to do it, but it's making numerics as you expand and removing them when you collapse each node.

```
public static List<NumericUpDown> lUpDown = new List<NumericUpDown>();      //List of Updowns we will be using


    private void treeView1_AfterExpand(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Node.Level != 0)  //Not adding a NumericUpDown on the Drinks tab
        {
            NumericUpDown newUpDown = new NumericUpDown() { Name = "upDown" + e.Node.Index.ToString() + "_" + e.Node.Parent.Index.ToString() };    //Making a NumericUpDown with a unique name linked to the index of the subnode(Apple juice = 0, Orange Juice = 1, ...) + "_" + index of the node(Drinks, ...) so you can add more subcategories, like food
            Controls.Add(newUpDown);    //Adding to the controls
            newUpDown.BringToFront();   //Bringing to front of the treeview
            lUpDown.Add(newUpDown);     //Adding to our list
        }
        UpdateLocations(e.Node.TreeView);   //Updating location of all NumericUpDowns
    }

    private void treeView1_AfterCollapse(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Node.Level == 0)
        {
            foreach (TreeNode subNode in e.Node.Nodes)          //Closing all subnodes which automatically will erase their NumericUpDowns
            {
                subNode.Collapse();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            NumericUpDown UpDownToRemove = lUpDown.Find(x => x.Name == "upDown" + e.Node.Index.ToString() + "_" + e.Node.Parent.Index.ToString());     //Finding by the index which NumericUpDown we'll remove
            Controls.Remove(UpDownToRemove);    //Removing from Controls
            lUpDown.Remove(UpDownToRemove);     //Removing from our list

            UpdateLocations(e.Node.TreeView);   //Updating location of all NumericUpDowns
        }
    }

    private void UpdateLocations(TreeView tv)
    {
        int index = 0;
        foreach (TreeNode Node in tv.Nodes)     //Going through all nodes in the TreeView(in this case, only Drinks)
        {
            foreach (TreeNode subNode in Node.Nodes)        //Going through all subnodes(childs of Drinks: Apple Juice, Orange Juice, ...)
            {
                index = subNode.Index;                      //Finding the index of the child
                if (subNode.IsExpanded)
                {
                    Point upDownLoc = subNode.FirstNode.Bounds.Location;                                //Geting the location of the Price tag
                    upDownLoc.X += 80;                                                                  //Adding some X points so it goes to the right
                    upDownLoc.Y += subNode.Bounds.Height - 5;                                           //Correcting the height
                    lUpDown.Find(x => x.Name == "upDown" + index.ToString() + "_" + subNode.Parent.Index.ToString()).Location = upDownLoc;      //Finding the correct UpDown to update location by the subnode index(Apple juice = 0, Orange Juice = 1, ...)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Hope it helps even it's a more complex way of doing it.
Here's a [gif](https://giphy.com/gifs/7FgZ2Lf1oGP6B496fL) of it working

Comment: glad I could help :D

Comment: Just made an adjustment so you can keep adding categories, like Drinks, Foods, and anything else.